# Iterate and change all occurrences of given fields in JSON

Tags: javascript, string, function, object, ecmascript-6

I have a `JSON` object.
I need to change values of all occurrences of a given field of it.
For example:

```
{
  email:"aaa@bbb.com",
  person: {  
    email:"dfd@ffds.com"  
  },  
  mother: {  
    name: "AAA",  
    email:"fdsfd@fdsfsd.com",  
    friend: {  
      email:"fdsd@gfsgf.com"  
    }
  }  
 }
```

I need to find all `email`fields and change their `values` based on their `values`.

I know how to iterate through one level of a `JSON`, I do not know how to iterate through all levels.

Thank you! :-)

Comment: change their values based on their values????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterating through json object javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323699/iterating-through-json-object-javascript)

Comment: @ellipsis yes, I want to take given email value and change it according to it's value.

Comment: like `if(email =='abc@xyz.com'){email = 'pqr@xyz.com'}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all this is not a `JSON` object, it is a simple JavaScript object.

Then you can use recursion to loop through all the `object` levels, and check if the iterated `property` holds an `object` so process it again otherwise if it's `email` so change it.

```
function process(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
      process(obj[key]);
    } else if (key == "email") {
      obj[key] = "new email value";
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**

I used the string `"new email value"` as new value for `email`, but you can change it accordingly with your desired `value`.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {
  email: "aaa@bbb.com",
  person: {
    email: "dfd@ffds.com"
  },
  mother: {
    name: "AAA",
    email: "fdsfd@fdsfsd.com",
    friend: {
      email: "fdsd@gfsgf.com"
    }
  }
}

function process(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
      process(obj[key]);
    } else if (key == "email") {
      obj[key] = "new email value";
    }
  }
}
process(data);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same style recursive function as in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54895702/10221765), just modify it slightly:

```
function changeEmail(obj, newEmail) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (key == "email") {
      obj[key] = newEmail;
    }
    if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
      changeEmail(obj[key], newEmail);
    }
  });
}
```